# Как выбрать string из БД, и отобразить его, без цикла?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть БД, где написан путь к папке. Мне надо выбрать его, и отобразить в echo. 
Я бы не писал сюда, но везде в интернете показаны примеры с циклом while.
Мне нужно просто выбрать один string из БД.
Вот сам БД: 
[image: котак]

Выделено красным на скрине. Вот этот текст мне надо отобразить в echo.
Я имею такой запрос SQL: `SELECT user_image FROM users WHERE login = '$login'`, но он нихера не работает.

Как мне получить результат, состоящий из одного пользователя, без использования цикла `while`.

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните, вы используете pdo или что-то другое?

Comment: @ИлхомжонМатазимов B покажите по каким параметрам делаете выборку, что у Вас несколько записей выходит.

Comment: Возьмите любой пример с циклом, уберите из него слово while (Оставив выражение, которое у него в круглых скобках) и соответствующие ему фигурные скобки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете PDO для подключения к СУБД, тогда следующий код для вас.

Обратите внимание на то что в вашем запросе есть проблема c [безопасностью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Лучше написать так:

```
$sth = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT user_image FROM users WHERE login = ?");
$sth->execute([$login]);

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result !== false){
 echo $result['user_image'];
}else{
  echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: Так же хочу обратить ваше внимание на SQL инъекцию.

Comment: Надо не "обращать внимание", а не допускать инъекцию в своем ответе

Comment: @Ипатьев, согласен, подправил

Answer (score -2):

`SELECT user_image FROM users WHERE login = '$login'`

Не совсем понимаю зачем вам переменная? 
Вы знаете конкретный логин?
Если вам необходимо первую строчку выбрать например,то там логин obitoihom, его используйте при составлении запроса.

`SELECT user_image FROM users WHERE login = 'obitoihom'`

Переменные тут не нужны.

Comment: Скорее всего `$login` является всё-таки переменным значением, а вот выборку нам ТС упростил.

Comment: В 99% кода в таких запросах используются переменные, потому что сайты разрабатываются для неограниченного количества пользователей и логин или другой идентификатор пользователя поступает извне явно или через сессию и в итоге оказывается в переменной в коде. Если же в коде будет явно указан логин то выходит данный код может работать только для одного единственного пользователя

Comment: Ну я не знаю постановку задачи,в любом случае ,если там значение хранится в переменной,то тогда достаточно просто выполнить запрос который по сути автор уже написал,просто не надо делать его в цикле. А как уже определяется эта переменная,я не могу знать из описания задачи.